# value % is not a member of type parameter T (Scala)

Tags: scala

This is really stupid, but I tried to write my first Scala program and found that:

```
def remainder[T](a:T, b:T):T = {
    a%b
}
```

gives me:

```
scala> :l d.scala
Loading d.scala...
<console>:8: error: value % is not a member of type parameter T
           a%b
            ^
```

Well, how do I tell Scala that T is numeric and defines math operations?
I don't believe that such simple thing requires knowing all dark corners of Scala. It must be something simple!
Well, I tried some combinations like "T:Numeric", but it did not help.

Comment: You define a method remainder which takes some Type, like String, JFrame, Socket, File, Float, Int and then you perform a modulo operation on it. How shall this work? `remainder ("FooBar", "Bar") ` will return what value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why but `Numeric` isn't restrictive enough.

```
def remainder[T](a:T, b:T)(implicit ev:Integral[T]):T =
  ev.rem(a,b)
```

...which can be sugared...

```
def remainder[T:Integral](a:T, b:T):T =
  implicitly[Integral[T]].rem(a,b)
```

...or prettified further...

```
import Integral.Implicits._

def remainder[T:Integral](a:T, b:T):T = a % b
```

Comment: probably because floating point types also have numeric instances right? so i guess reminder wouldn't make much sense?

Comment: @DominicEgger; When I go to the REPL I find that `4.53 % 1.1` is allowed. I know that division is different for `Integral` (`quot(a,b)`) and `Fractional` (`div(a,b)`) but I don't find the `Fractional` equivalent of `rem(a,b)`.

Comment: for the 3rd version, it says: `error: not found: value Integral`

Comment: @18446744073709551615; Works for me both in REPL (Scala 2.12.2) and IDE worksheet (Scala 2.12.4).

Comment: Upgraded to 2.12.5, and everything worked. At the expense of explicit `.asInstanceOf[T]` and `.toInt`.

Comment: Consider complex numbers (even if they aren't in the standard library).